# Setting system property application.secret for Play and initialization order

Tags: scala, playframework, netty

I'm using `NettyServerComponents` to embed *Play* in my application server and I'm having problems with setting the required "application.secret" programatically.

The call I make is:

```
System.setProperty("application.secret", secret)
```

and I can verify that it is set via `System.getProperty("application.secret")`. However initialization will fail if I put the call inside the class that encapsulates and starts the server with this:

```
Exception in thread "main" @6m0lkl2h5: Configuration error
  at play.api.libs.CryptoConfigParser.get$lzycompute(Crypto.scala:235)
  at play.api.libs.CryptoConfigParser.get(Crypto.scala:204)
  at play.api.BuiltInComponents$class.cryptoConfig(Application.scala:275)
  ...
```

If I move the same `setProperty` call earlier in the code, it works just fine.

Is there some `import` for play that causes system properties to be read and cached? Or some other reason why it's not seeing the value i can see via `getProperty`?

Comment: So your question is only concerning the `application.secret` not any other arbitrary config key, true?

Comment: I suppose, if i end up having so set any other key this way, the same question will apply. `application.secret` is the one that's currently illustrating that where in my code i call `setProperty` matters and i'm trying to figure out why

Comment: This seems to be due to the way `CryptoConfigParser` is written (a non lazy val in a singleton object which is loaded before property is set). By using `lazy` values you can achieve the caching requirement (defer reading the property to the first usage). By the way as a workaround you can use [environment variables](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ProductionConfiguration#Using-environment-variables)

Comment: What's confusing me is that i can initialize via `setProperty` as long as i put it earlier in my code. I've not yet found what import brings the CryptoConfig initialization into scope. Time to dig into Play source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the initialization order problem and while it is rather specific to my setup, I wanted to post my answer in case someone ends up in a similar situation.

Configuration of play when using `NettyServerComponents` happens via this line:

```
lazy val configuration: Configuration = Configuration(ConfigFactory.load())
```

`ConfigFactory.load()` is part of `com.typesafe.config` and statically initializes configuration on first access. The daemon that I'm embedding Play in also uses this configuration via `net.ceedubs.ficus.FicusConfig` which means that even though the above line is a lazy initialization, my code had previously called `ConfigFactory.load()` for its own configuration, meaning that setting the `application.secret` via `setProperty` had no effect.

For bonus fun, since both sets of code use `ConfigFactory.load()`, i just had to put

```
application {
  secret = "foo"
}
```

In my existing config file and Play picked it up from there.